# mvc html how to create datetimepicker how to do

Tags: html, model-view-controller, datetimepicker

i want to create a datetimepicker usgin html in my mvc application
i have the control below

```
      <div class="col-md-3">
                        @Html.TextBox(model => model.Trip_Time, "{yyyy-MM-dd 12:00:00}", new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Trip_Time)
                    </div>
```

and the jquery code is

```
    $("#Trip_Time").datetimepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            showSecond: true,
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
            timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss",

     
        });
```

the problem is when i click on the text box which is read only nothing is show

Comment: remove this code @readonly = true . if you want show datetimepicker

Comment: not showing anything if i click the text box